# Xamarin Studio on Windows 10 (10162) terminating immediately after opening

Tags: windows, xamarin, windows-10

Is there an issue with Xamarin Studio (v5.9.3) on Windows 10 build 10162? Coz previously before this build I could open Xamarin just fine. Did Microsoft shift some .NET things or did Xamarin updates affect the app?

I know Windows 10 has not yet been release for public use, but if this is the experience I am getting then devs who want to update to Windows 10 would be unable to use it. Is there a workaround or fix available?

Comment: It would really help if you told us what is *not working*. Any error message?

Comment: It terminates immediately i try opening. 
Log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcsd1vvkfw9qoqc/Ide.2015-07-09__11-09-12.log?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the version you have installed, then check if you have the latest version of dotnet 4.5 installed the JDK from java in version 7.55 and then download the most current version of the installed the www.xamarin.com\download and install Xamarin again leaving all the default options enabled. I'm using the same version of Windows and 10 had no problems with the tool.

Comment: I updated my W10 to build 10166 and in this version Xamarin Studio works. I think it was the .NET framework issue. 
Would have upvoted the answer but im a nubie to Stackoverflow, i dont have enough reputation.
Thanks.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply, could be the same problem in .NET even escape me this question, and I also already had some similar problems.